# Copying Data from one sheet to the last row of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm trying to make something in Excel work, but I cannot.
I have 2 Sheets
Sheet 1 is the "main sheet"
Sheet 2 has a filter.
I want 2 filtered columns to be copied to the main sheet and pasted at the end of the already existing content.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: I suggest to do some research here, because the question how to copy filtered data to another sheet has already been asked many times and there exist a bunch of solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - you will need to update the ranges/sheet names as required.

```
Sub CopyDataLastRow()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim CopyLastRow As Long
Dim DestLastRow As Long

'Set Variables
Set wsCopy = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Update your sheet name as required.
Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet2") 'Update your sheet name as required.
   
'Find Last Row in Copy Range
CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Find 1st blank row in Destination Range - Offset 1 row
DestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

'Copy & Paste Data
wsCopy.Range("A2:B" & CopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("A" & DestLastRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much!